# Mysql Mariadb recursive query

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `name`, `parentid`) VALUES
(1, 'categ 1', 0),
(2, 'xcateg 1.1', 1),
(3, 'acateg 1.2', 1),
(4, 'categ 1.2.1', 3),
(5, 'categ 2', 0),
(6, 'categ 2.1', 5);
```

and a recursive query on it :

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree_search (id, name, lvl, parentid) AS (
  SELECT   id, name, 0, parentid
  FROM tbl
  WHERE parentid = 0

  UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.name,
    ts.lvl + 1, ts.id
    FROM tbl AS t
  JOIN tree_search AS ts ON t.parentid = ts.id
)
SELECT * FROM tree_search
ORDER BY parentid, lvl, name;
```

which works and prints the following result :

```
id  |    name      | lvl   | parentid |
----+--------------+-------+----------+
  1 | categ 1      |     0 |        0 |
  5 | categ 2      |     0 |        0 |
  3 | acateg 1.2   |     1 |        1 |
  2 | xcateg 1.1   |     1 |        1 |
  4 | categ 1.2.1  |     2 |        3 |
  6 | categ 2.1    |     1 |        5 |
```

I would have liked to add an extra column to the result, namely "parent_name". How do I do this?

Edited to add: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376973/2027239
That was the answer on an older question which I used to build my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inner join of tbl

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
>   `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `parentid` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `name`, `parentid`) VALUES
> (1, 'categ 1', 0),
> (2, 'xcateg 1.1', 1),
> (3, 'acateg 1.2', 1),
> (4, 'categ 1.2.1', 3),
> (5, 'categ 2', 0),
> (6, 'categ 2.1', 5);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE tree_search (id, name, lvl, parentid) AS (
>   SELECT   id, name, 0, parentid
>   FROM tbl
>   WHERE parentid = 0
>
>   UNION ALL
>     SELECT t.id, t.name,
>     ts.lvl + 1, ts.id
>     FROM tbl AS t
>   JOIN tree_search AS ts ON t.parentid = ts.id
> )
> SELECT t.*, tb.`name` FROM tree_search t inner Join tbl tb ON t.parentid = tb.id 
> ORDER BY parentid, lvl, t.name;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name        | lvl | parentid | name      
> -: | :---------- | --: | -------: | :---------
>  3 | acateg 1.2  |   1 |        1 | categ 1   
>  2 | xcateg 1.1  |   1 |        1 | categ 1   
>  4 | categ 1.2.1 |   2 |        3 | acateg 1.2
>  6 | categ 2.1   |   1 |        5 | categ 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a67d18662e498a3409dca12103cd82d7)*

Or use `left join` to get all `id`s even those which have no parent.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
>   `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `parentid` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `name`, `parentid`) VALUES
> (1, 'categ 1', 0),
> (2, 'xcateg 1.1', 1),
> (3, 'acateg 1.2', 1),
> (4, 'categ 1.2.1', 3),
> (5, 'categ 2', 0),
> (6, 'categ 2.1', 5);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE tree_search (id, name, lvl, parentid) AS (
>   SELECT   id, name, 0, parentid
>   FROM tbl
>   WHERE parentid = 0
>
>   UNION ALL
>     SELECT t.id, t.name,
>     ts.lvl + 1, ts.id
>     FROM tbl AS t
>   JOIN tree_search AS ts ON t.parentid = ts.id
> )
> SELECT t.*, tb.`name` FROM tree_search t LEFT Join tbl tb ON t.parentid = tb.id 
> ORDER BY parentid, lvl, t.name;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name        | lvl | parentid | name      
> -: | :---------- | --: | -------: | :---------
>  1 | categ 1     |   0 |        0 | null      
>  5 | categ 2     |   0 |        0 | null      
>  3 | acateg 1.2  |   1 |        1 | categ 1   
>  2 | xcateg 1.1  |   1 |        1 | categ 1   
>  4 | categ 1.2.1 |   2 |        3 | acateg 1.2
>  6 | categ 2.1   |   1 |        5 | categ 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=030be7d5d0ccd4a0c96cf91d051ec211)*

Comment: I think you should recommend an outer join.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - can you explain, please? I understand what this does and as there is no ```parent_name``` for a category with ```parentid = 0```, then I find it both natural and logical to use the ```inner join```.  What would be the interest of a ```full outer join```?

Comment: mysql has no full outer join.  but Gordon means a left join  like here to show also all ID that have no oparent https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=030be7d5d0ccd4a0c96cf91d051ec211